# Yarn link works for one file but throws error for another file in same Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build an Angular project where I have 3 files - getComputers.js, getIps.js and one typescript file - app.ts. I need to require a trendmicro module in both Javascript files. For one file it works but for the other it throws a module not found error.

I ran the following line to link the trendmicro module to my project.

```
yarn link "@trendmicro/deepsecurity"
```

It gets successfully linked. The problem shows up for getIps.js and doesn't show up for getComputers.js, here is what I tried:

getComputers.js

```
function getThoseComps(p1,p2)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const api = require("@trendmicro/deepsecurity");   //This works
         //...other code
    });
}
```

getIps.js

```
function getIPS(p3,p4)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const api = require("@trendmicro/deepsecurity");   //This throws error...
         //...other code
    });  
}
```

app.ts

```
import { getThoseComps } from "../../assets/js/geComputers.js"
import { getIPS } from "../../assets/js/getIps.js";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    async fetchComputers() {
        try {
            const obj1 = await getThoseComps(p1,p2); // This works perfect
            const obj2 = await getIPS(p3,p4);     // This causes error...  
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.fetchComputers();
    } 
}
```

Edit:

```
ERROR in /home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ApiClient' in '/home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src'
ERROR in /home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/APIKeysApi' in '/home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src'
ERROR in /home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src/index.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/WebReputationRights' in '/home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src'
ERROR in /home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/WeeklyScheduleParameters' in '/home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src'
ERROR in /home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model/WorkspaceVirtualMachineSummary' in '/home/hd/Downloads/dsm-js-sdk/src'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Note: The error shows up for index.js which according to me is misleading becuase the same error doesn't show up when I require trendmicro module in getComputers.js file. The dsm-js-sdk folder contains that module.

Comment: post the error logs with your questions, please.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I posted the error logs.

Comment: Its better to post the error logs as text in the post itself. I am running behind a proxy right now and i am not able to see the Error log.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan no problem. I added it there. Please check it out.